# How to use handsontable library in angular 2

Tags: typescript, npm, handsontable, angular2-components, angular2-cli

I am new to configuration part in npm, i am trying to use handsontable library in angular 2 project created using angular-cli (ng init). I added the typescript definition for the same.

Here is my app.compponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const myData = [
            ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
        ];

        const config = {
            data: myData,
            colHeaders: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
            startRows: 5,
            startCols: 5,
            minSpareCols: 1,
            //always keep at least 1 spare row at the right
            minSpareRows: 1
            //always keep at least 1 spare row at the bottom,
        };
        (<any>$("#test")).handsontable(config);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>
  <div id ="test"></div>
</h1>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularStart2</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

gives me error:

```
ReferenceError: Handsontable is not defined at r.fn.init.$.fn.handsontable (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:87583:26) at AppComponent.ngAfterViewInit (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:79:20)
```

I have also tried to import in below way

```
import {Handsontable} from 'handsontable';
```

and it gives me following error

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'numbro'
    at newRequire (handsontable.js:53) [<root>]
    at :8000/vendor.bundle.js:102461:16 [<root>]
    at Object.23.cellTypes (handsontable.js:4439) [<root>]
    at newRequire (handsontable.js:58) [<root>]
```

I have tried all ways from https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/3627

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At present, HandsOnTable officially do not support Angular 2. Refer Forum reference [here](https://forum.handsontable.com/t/angular2-handsontable/766). It is planned for Q1 this year. You can leave your vote for this feature [here](https://trello.com/b/PztR4hpj/handsontable-roadmap-2017-login-to-vote)

Hence, you will have to use handsontable js & css files directly into angular2 app like this-

**Step1**: In Index.html, add these 2 lines-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.30.1/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css">

<script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.30.1/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
```

**Step2**: Sample AppComponent.ts looks like this-

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var Handsontable: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
<h3>Angular2 Final 2.0.0</h3>
<h2>Handsontable Performance Test (10000x100)</h2>

<div id="example"></div>
    `
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit { 

container: any;
hot: any;

ngAfterViewInit() {
this.container = document.getElementById('example');

this.hot = new Handsontable(this.container, {
  data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(10000, 100),
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  // performance tip: set constant size
  colWidths: 80,
  rowHeights: 23,
  // performance tip: turn off calculations
  autoRowSize: false,
  autoColSize: false,
});

}

}
```

**Result Output**:

[image: Result]

**Please note** - I am using angular2 Final version 2.0.0

Comment: I'm having the same exactly error with angular1.5. Is it something known? Is there another way to make it work? (related question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122567/handsontable-related-error-cannot-find-modules-numbro-moment-pikaday-zeroclip) )

Comment: Can we use something like hot: Handsontable; instead of   hot: any;           If yes how ?

Comment: @Vaibhav give a try and see what happens.

Comment: Not working for me too - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null -  I have the pro version and bought based

Comment: Hello @Sanket ,
Can i get the HotModule using your approach to import inside Module.ts file and use as directive inside html file like : <hotTable></hotTable> ?

Comment: Apologies @KunalKakkad I havent tried new handsontable yet. Refer this [link](https://handsontable.github.io/angular-handsontable/quick-start)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response,

@TSW I tried to install both packages "numbro" as well as "pikaday" but it didnt worked out.

@Sanket thanks for solution but as i am using angular cli i found that adding following snippet in angular-cli.json works

```
"scripts": [
            "./../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "./../node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"
        ],
```

Could this be possible only by importing handsontable by declaring it in package.json as handsontable downloads numbro and pikaday by itself. why it is needed to use "handsontable.full.min.js"

Comment: Hello,
I am facing same error but still i am unable to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer our question for now, but development on the official wrapper for Angular 2+ is [scheduled for June](https://github.com/handsontable/angular2-handsontable/issues/1#issuecomment-300148578).

**Update (August 29, 2017):** We now see progress on the development of the official Angular2+ wrapper, which may be found here: https://github.com/handsontable/angular-handsontable

Comment: I bought the pro version based on a release of May. And as of now from there  iffy support for pro users there appears to be no date for release.