# Handsontable related error cannot find modules numbro, moment, pikaday, ZeroClipboard

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, handsontable

I've added **handsontable-pro**, **numbro**, **moment**, **pikaday** and **ZeroClipboard** in my `package.json` dependencies, e.g.:

```
"dependencies": {
    "numbro": "^1.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    ...
 }
```

and imported these libraries in my angular1.5 `app.ts` file like this:

```
import 'handsontable-pro';
import 'numbro';
import 'moment';
...
```

After running `npm install`, `npm run build` and also building and running my project, I'm getting the following error in the console of the developers tools of Chrome:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'numbro'
    at newRequire (handsontable.js:48)
    at handsontable.js:55
    at Object.23.cellTypes (handsontable.js:4238)
    at newRequire (handsontable.js:53)
    at handsontable.js:55
    at Object.125.../node_modules/hot-builder/node_modules/handsontable/src/browser (handsontable.js:21831)
    at newRequire (handsontable.js:53)
    at outer (handsontable.js:61)
    at handsontable.js:66
    at handsontable.js:22
```

And also for the rest of the modules. Any ideas on that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

run this command 
`npm install angular-handsontable`
this will install the required dependency.

https://handsontable.github.io/angular-handsontable/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

Some of these dependencies need to be exposed globally. If you are using webpack you can do it as follows:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      { 
          test: /(\.js)|(\.jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/, 
          use: [{ 
              loader: 'babel-loader', 
              options: {
                  presets: ['react', 'es2015']
               }
          }]
      }, {
          test: require.resolve('numbro'),
          use: [{
              loader: 'expose-loader',
              options: 'numbro'
          }]
        }, {
          test: require.resolve('moment'),
          use: [{
              loader: 'expose-loader',
              options: 'moment'
          }]
        }, {
          test: require.resolve('pikaday'),
          use: [{
              loader: 'expose-loader',
              options: 'Pikaday'
          }]
        }, {
          test: require.resolve('zeroclipboard'),
          use: [{
              loader: 'expose-loader',
              options: 'ZeroClipboard'
          }]
        }
    ]
  },
```